# How To call 'sidebar.phtml' in cart pop up

Tags: magento-1.9, sidebar

I am using `magento 1.9.2.3`. In my `header.phtml` when I call the cart sidebar like

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar'); ?>`

the sidebar is not getting displayed when hovered over the cart icon. Also I enabled it in backend.

Below is my cart. Kindly help me to enable the sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one more alternative to perform this task. Please follow below steps:

1. Go to you theme folder  i.e

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/page.xml

Find the code given below:

```
<block type="page/html_header" as="header">
```

And past the cart sidebar block shown below:

```
<block name="header" as="header">     
<block name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>     
<block name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>     
<block name="top.menu" as="topMenu"/>     
<!--Add cart sidebar block -->     
<block name="cart_sidebar" as="headerCart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>     
</block>
```

2. : And now, in template file header.phtml

> (app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/page/html/header.phtml),

call cart sidebar block as a child in header

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headerCart')?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try with direct block calling method

```
<?php
          echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')
          ->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml')
          ->toHtml(); ?>
```